# Build a war/ear file for JavaFX web start applications

Tags: netbeans, javafx, javafx-8, war, java-web-start

What's the easiest way to do this?  Do we need to just create a regular war Ant task ourselves, or is there some easier way, with Netbeans?  I have the usual /dist folder containing all the files needed (jnlp, jar, html, etc), but I don't want to have to copy those files over separately, and preferably they'd be zipped up into a war automatically.

Comment: Creating a WAR/EAR is solved.  Ant and Maven can both do it.  You are allowing an imagined inefficiency to be a problem.

Comment: No, really?  Not helpful.  What I'm asking is whether Netbeans has a way of doing this for you, for convenience, and what the best way to do this is.  If it's just creating the task in Ant yourself, that's fine, as long as NB isn't going to overwrite that task.

Comment: The task exists.  Just write a build.xml you're done.  Don't know NetBeans; IntelliJ does this with no problem.

Comment: I have a build.xml that NB generates.  It's not obvious whether or not it'll mangle anything I add manually.  Regardless, obviously you don't have any suggestions I couldn't come up with on my own here...  I never said this was a "problem" anywhere.  I guess SO is a poor place to ask for best practices or advice that isn't a text book copy/paste.

Comment: @duffymo I think the question is whether the built-in process in Netbeans (for JavaFX projects) that generates the jnlp, jar, and html files can be integrated with a process that builds a war file. I.e. the OP wants to have a single build process that includes the default JavaFX build process and incorporates a war file build.

Comment: Yeah I would agree with that.

Comment: You might want to create some maven-project, where multiple outcomes are possible, e.g. using the normal war-package-type and adding the [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) in addition to the war-project.